# xUnit tests under F# : It looks like you're trying to execute an xUnit.net unit test ('System.ArgumentException' occurred in xunit.runner.utility.dll)

Tags: f#, xunit

## 0. My setup is as follows

```
Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, update 3, v.11.0.60610.01
Visual F# 2012 04940-004-0038003-02527
TestDriven.Net 3.5 Beta 3 Personal
```

## 1. What I have in packages.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <packages>
      <package id="FsUnit.xUnit" version="1.2.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
      <package id="xunit" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net45" />
    </packages>
```

## 2. What I ran: `xunit.installer.exe`

## 3. This is what the packages folder looks like

```
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2
\packages\xunit.1.9.1
\packages\repositories.config
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\Lib
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\tools
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2.nupkg
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2.nuspec
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\Lib\Net20
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\Lib\Net40
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\Lib\Net20\FsUnit.CustomMatchers.dll
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\Lib\Net20\FsUnit.CustomMatchers.XML
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\Lib\Net20\FsUnit.Xunit.dll
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\Lib\Net20\FsUnit.Xunit.xml
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\Lib\Net20\NHamcrest.dll
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\Lib\Net40\FsUnit.CustomMatchers.dll
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\Lib\Net40\FsUnit.CustomMatchers.XML
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\Lib\Net40\FsUnit.Xunit.dll
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\Lib\Net40\FsUnit.Xunit.xml
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\Lib\Net40\NHamcrest.dll
\packages\FsUnit.xUnit.1.2.1.2\tools\install.ps1
\packages\xunit.1.9.1\lib
\packages\xunit.1.9.1\xunit.1.9.1.nupkg
\packages\xunit.1.9.1\xunit.1.9.1.nuspec
\packages\xunit.1.9.1\lib\net20
\packages\xunit.1.9.1\lib\net20\xunit.dll
\packages\xunit.1.9.1\lib\net20\xunit.dll.tdnet
\packages\xunit.1.9.1\lib\net20\xunit.installer.exe
\packages\xunit.1.9.1\lib\net20\xunit.runner.msbuild.dll
\packages\xunit.1.9.1\lib\net20\xunit.runner.tdnet.dll
\packages\xunit.1.9.1\lib\net20\xunit.runner.utility.dll
\packages\xunit.1.9.1\lib\net20\xunit.xml
```

## 4. My test file:

```
module MyTesting

open Xunit
open FsUnit.Xunit

[<Fact>]
let ``please work``() = 123
```

And I am still getting this:

```
------ Test started: Assembly: MyTesting.dll ------

It looks like you're trying to execute an xUnit.net unit test.

For xUnit 1.5 or above (recommended):
Please ensure that the directory containing your 'xunit.dll' reference also contains xUnit's
test runner files ('xunit.dll.tdnet', 'xunit.runner.tdnet.dll' etc.)

For earlier versions:
You need to install support for TestDriven.Net using xUnit's 'xunit.installer.exe' application.

You can find xUnit.net downloads and support here:
http://www.codeplex.com/xunit
```

A question:

**What am I doing wrong?**

UPDATE:

This is what is says when I run in the debug mode:

```
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET 3\ProcessInvocation86.exe'
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET 3\TestDriven.TestRunner.Server.dll'
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET 3\TestDriven.TestRunner.dll'
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET 3\TestDriven.Framework.dll'
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Mine\MyProject\packages\xunit.1.9.1\lib\net20\xunit.runner.tdnet.dll'
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Mine\MyProject\bin\Debug\MyProject.Testing.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Mine\MyProject\packages\xunit.1.9.1\lib\net20\xunit.runner.utility.dll'
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'xunit.runner.utility.{Dynamic}'
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in xunit.runner.utility.dll
The thread 'TestRunnerThread' (0x13b0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET 3\AdHoc\TestDriven.AdHoc.dll'
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Mine\MyProject.Testing\bin\Debug\MyProject.Testing.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ProcessInvocation86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Mine\MyProject\MyProject.Testing\bin\Debug\xunit.dll'
The thread 'TestRunnerThread' (0x504) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[1136] ProcessInvocation86.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running xUnit 1.9 from TestDriven.NET 3.3 Beta 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030404/running-xunit-1-9-from-testdriven-net-3-3-beta-2)

Comment: @GuyCoder, `Visual F# 2012 04940-004-0038003-02527`
and `TestDriven.Net 3.5 Beta 3 Personal`

Comment: @RubenBartelink, it's not a duplicate, that guy didn't know what he was doing, my problem is different (with the same symptoms though)

Comment: Wow, `A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in xunit.runner.utility.dll`

Answer (score 2):

I can't repro this.

Here is what I did:

1. Open VS2013, TD.NET 3.5 RC
2. Create an F# project, Windows -> Library (.NET 4.5)
3. Ran "install-package xunit -version 1.9.1" from the Package Manager Console
4. Ran "install-package fsunit.xunit -version 1.2.1.2" from the Package Manager Console
5. Replaced the contents of Library1.fs with:

```
module FsTestSample

open Xunit
open FsUnit.Xunit

[<Fact>]
let ``please work``() = 123
```

I placed the cursor inside "please work" and right clicked, then clicked on "Run Test(s)". The test ran, with this output:

```
------ Test started: Assembly: FsTestSample.dll ------

1 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, took 0.50 seconds (xUnit.net 1.9.1 build 1600).
```

I even changed "= 123" to "= 123 / 0" just to verify that the test failed with a divide by zero exception (it did).

Comment: Note that xunit.installer.exe is deprecated for TD.NET, and should not be used. If you have used it, please run it again to uninstall the xUnit.net support for TD.NET, because it has been dynamically discovered for several years now.

Comment: my setup is slightly different, please check out the update (point #0), also note: 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in xunit.runner.utility.dll

Comment: Did you undo the installation from xunit.installer like I suggested?

Comment: @967 you run `xunit.installer.exe` and untick the TD.NET box.

Comment: I noticed that you have xunit.installer.exe in your packages folder, but that's not part of the NuGet package. I suspect you've copied some incorrect files over top of the files from the NuGet package, and this mismatch of file versions is causing your problems. This ZIP file contains my functional example: http://sdrv.ms/1cW5uAj

Comment: Ok guys, I tried uninstalling it didn't help, however I found the reason at `Xunit.ExecutorWrapper..ctor(String assemblyFilename, String configFilename, Boolean shadowCopy)` it says `Could not find file: C:\Mine\MyProject\f` which means that it breaks because there is a `#` sign in the folder path: `C:\Mine\MyProject\f#\`, not sure what you going to do about it as it seems that's a .NET problem

Comment: Okay, that narrows it down significantly. It is common to convert assembly code base paths into local paths using the Uri class. It would appear that that breaks with #, because it considers that to be a hash in the URL sense, and cuts off the file path there. Weak sauce. :-p I've opened an issue for this: https://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9907

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. *your Fact is broken*:-

   If you hover over the

   `please work`

   bit, you'll see something like: `unit -> int`

   For a `Fact` to be picked up by an xUnit runner, it needs to yield `unit (void).

   Hence, one key thing to get right first is to not return anything. In other words, replace your `123` with `()` (or an Assertion).

   You can guard against this by putting a `:unit` stipulation on the test:-

   ```
   [<Fact>]
   let ``please work`` () : unit = 123
   ```

   This will force a compilation error.
2. *TestDriven.NET* cannot find the xunit.tdnet modules

   Either try the VS-based runner which should work as long as it's installed and xunit.dll is getting to your output dir or look at the docs for your version of TD.NET for detailed troubleshooting notes (exec summary is if the .tdnet file was in your out dir or you undo and redo the xunit.installer from the folder containing the packages it should just work, esp if you are on latest)

Comment: Turns out TestDriven.net's message if its not a correct Fact is just very confusing - see my VTC vote. Can you close please>

Comment: Just tried let ``please work``() = printf "Working!" same problem. So point #1 isn't the case. Built-in VS test runner works, but it's not what I am looking for. Also I ran it in a debug mode and this is what it said: `A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in xunit.runner.utility.dll`, check out the update

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it. So the reason turned out to be that the path to folder that contained the project had a `#` sign in it (..\F#..). I hope this can save you some headache. If it doesn't and the reason is different here is what you gotta do:

1. In Visual Studio go `Debug` >> `Exceptions...`
2. Enable breaking on `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` by setting a corresponding checkbox in the `Thrown` column.
3. Run your test in the Debug mode via the TD.NET: `[Right click on the test function]` >> `Test with` >> `Debugger`
4. The debugger should stop at whatever problem (exception) you have.